# Why won't it revolve?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a rotating ellipse to the center, and I'm having trouble as to how it isn't moving besides being in the draw and having an offset in x and y changing. I mapped the initial x and y position of the ellipses at first and try and calculated its distance from the center I was wondering if any of you could help, it'll be much appreciated. ^^ (beginner here) [IDE processing]

I dunno what's wrong with the revolution from polar to cartesian coord.

```
Heart heart = new Heart();

int h = 500;
int w = 500;

void setup(){

  size(500,500);
  heart = new Heart();
  heart.init();
  //heart.display();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  heart.rotate();

}

class Heart {

  float[][] pos;
  float[] dist;
  int hold;
  float xOff;
  float yOff;

  Heart(){
    hold = 10;
    dist = new float[hold];
    pos = new float[hold][hold];
  }

  void init(){
    for(int i = 0; i < hold; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < hold; j++){
        pos[i][j] = random(0,h);
      }
    }
  }

  /*void display(){
    for (int k = 0; k < hold; k++){
      fill(0,10,255,50);
      ellipse(pos[k][0],pos[0][k],15,15);
      stroke(255);
      line(w/2,h/2,pos[k][0],pos[0][k]);
    }
  }*/

  void rotate(){
    float[] r = new float[hold];
    int theta;

    for(int k = 0; k < hold; k++){
      r[k] = dist(w/2,h/2,pos[k][0],pos[0][k]);
      for(theta = 0; theta <= TWO_PI; theta++){
        xOff = r[k] * cos(theta);
        yOff = r[k] * sin(theta);
        stroke(255);
        println(pos[k][0] + xOff);
        ellipse(pos[k][0] + xOff,pos[0][k] + yOff,15,15);
      }
    }


  }
}
```

I expect the ellipses to revolve, no error.

Comment: What is `TWO_PI`? Why is your angle an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a global variable `angle` of type `float`. Increment the angle in every frame and pass it to the method `Heart.rotate()`:

```java
float angle = 0.0;
void draw(){
    background(0);
    heart.rotate(angle);
    angle += 0.01;
}
```

The method `Heart.rotate()` hast to draw the the `ellipse` with one certain angle i every frame, rather than all the possible angles in a loop in each frame.

```java
class Heart {

    // ...

    void rotate(float theta){
        float[] r = new float[hold];

        for(int k = 0; k < hold; k++){
            r[k] = dist(w/2,h/2,pos[k][0],pos[0][k]);

            xOff = r[k] * cos(theta);
            yOff = r[k] * sin(theta);
            stroke(255);
            println(pos[k][0] + xOff);
            ellipse(pos[k][0] + xOff,pos[0][k] + yOff,15,15);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the display is updated once after global [`draw()`](https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html) has been executed. There is no update of the display in the inner loop of the method `Heart.rotate()`.